# Running cloud9 on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud9-ide

Just installed cloud9 on ec2 using the instructions at https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.
All went well.
Opened 3131 in aws security group
Added dir cloud9/projects
IDE pops right up and the crashed when I do pretty much anything

```
Console
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-0-35 cloud9]$ bin/cloud9.sh -l 0.0.0.0 -w projects
mkdir -p plugins-client/lib.ace/www/worker
rm -rf /tmp/c9_worker_build
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/c9_worker_build/ext/codecomplete’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/c9_worker_build/ext/csslanguage’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/c9_worker_build/ext/linereport’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/c9_worker_build/ext/jslanguage’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/c9_worker_build/ext/linereport_php’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/c9_worker_build/ext/language’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/c9_worker_build/ext/htmllanguage’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/c9_worker_build/ext/linereport_python’: Permission denied
make: *** [plugins-client/lib.ace/www/worker/worker-language.js] Error 1
Linux 64 bit
connect plugin start
Connect server listening at http://x.x.x.x.0:3131 x.x.x.x replaces zeros in url
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  auth
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  git
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  gittools
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  hg
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  npm
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  filelist
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  search
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  revisions
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  settings
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  shell
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  state
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  watcher
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  node-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  npm-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  python-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  apache-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  ruby-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  php-runtime
Started '/home/ec2-user/cloud9/configs/default'!
IDE server initialized. Listening on x.x.x.x.0:3131 x.x.x.x replaces zeros in url

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1000:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:791:34)
```

Has anyone any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

In general `ENOENT` means there's some issue with symlinks, sockets, pipes, files, directories, etc.. either something doesn't exist or you don't have permissions to access it. I'm going to guess something socket or directory related here.

There's also a much easier way to run Cloud9 on EC2 now: https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/